# Discord bot, how to get all connected "guilds/servers"

Tags: javascript, bots, discord.js

I'm trying to use `client.guilds` , but it just seems to return this really weird object that I have no idea how to parse.

Object:

```
GuildManager {
  cacheType: [Function: Collection],
  cache: Collection(1) [Map] {
    '11111111111111111' => Guild {
      members: [GuildMemberManager],
      channels: [GuildChannelManager],
      roles: [RoleManager],
      presences: [PresenceManager],
      voiceStates: [VoiceStateManager],
      deleted: false,
      available: true,
      id: '1111111111111111111',
      shardID: 0,
      name: 'My Server Name',
      icon: '11111111111111111111111111111',
      splash: null,
      region: 'us-west',
      memberCount: 46,
      large: false,
      features: [],
      applicationID: null,
      afkTimeout: 300,
      afkChannelID: null,
      systemChannelID: null,
      embedEnabled: undefined,
      premiumTier: 0,
      premiumSubscriptionCount: 0,
      verificationLevel: 'NONE',
      explicitContentFilter: 'DISABLED',
      mfaLevel: 0,
      joinedTimestamp: 1590266012969,
      defaultMessageNotifications: 'ALL',
      systemChannelFlags: [SystemChannelFlags],
      vanityURLCode: null,
      description: null,
      banner: null,
      rulesChannelID: null,
      publicUpdatesChannelID: null,
      ownerID: '111111111111111111',
      emojis: [GuildEmojiManager]
    }
  }
}
```

I just simply don't know how to parse this to get the name of the servers I'm connected to. Right now I'm only connected to one server but in the future there will be more, I just want to ideally be able to say:

```
client.guilds.forEach(server => {
    console.log(guild.name+" id: "+guild.id);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This object is basic collection you can iterate over.

```
client.guilds.forEach(server => {
    console.log(server.name + " (id: " + server.id + ")");
});
```

Comment: this is exactly what I wrote at the bottom, it doesn't work.

Comment: This is not exactly the same. Have you checked this?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had to reference the cache object:

```
client.guilds.cache.forEach(server => {
    console.log(server.name + " id: " + server.id);
});
```